# What's causing "MissingInternetConnectionBlock" on Visual Studio 2015 install?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have tried to install Visual Studio 2015 3 times and it won't do it correctly. After running the installer it appears with an error saying "MissingInternetConnectionBlock: Cannot connect to the internet" even though I am writing this question as I am trying to install it. I have tried to just hit `Continue` and see if the install works anyway, sadly it does not, failing to download several of the extensions that are crucial to the project. How to I get rid of the `MissingInternetConnectionBlock` error and hopefully download everything correctly?

Answer (score 1):

After some poking around and various different attempts, something said "Visual Studio works best with Internet Explorer which you don't have." Even though I did have it. For development reasons I had IE9 installed, after upgrading to IE11 the error has gone away and the install is proceeding as expected.